# Git Clone Too many authentication failures for root

Tags: git, ssh, git-clone

Установлен Git на машине с Win 7 64
При любой попытке склонировать что-то из удалённого репозитория пишет следующее

```
$ git clone ssh://root@<address>/gittest test
Cloning into 'test'...
fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: root
Access denied
Access denied
Access denied
Access denied
▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒: Server sent disconnect message
type 2 (protocol error):
"Too many authentication failures for root"
```

Если просто подключаюсь по ssh, то всё нормально

```
$ ssh root@<address>
root@<address>'s password:
```

Подскажите как исправить проблему с git, пожалуйста.

PS Поставил программу SourceTree. С помощью неё всё получается склонировать, но хотелось бы разобраться, почему не получается сделать это через сам Git.

Comment: Git как устанавливали отдельно или в через MSYS2 ?

Comment: Отдельно устанавливал

Comment: Я когда устанавливал отдельно , подобные ошибки происходили. некорректно были настроены переменые окружения.  Сейчас пользуюсь MSYS2 , там все переменые настроены проблемы непроисходило.

Comment: Кстати, если у вас открыт парольный доступ к руту - закрывайте. Взламывают только так. Вообще рекомендую закрывать пароли везде и логиниться через ssh-ключи.

Comment: а если убрать `ssh://`, ошибка такая же?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin другая. fatal error о том, что сервер не существует

Comment: @mrx, приведите, пожалуйста, текст команды максимально близко к тому, что вы вводите. цифры/буквы, конечно, можете заменить для пущей секретности.

Comment: Возможно, не открою Америку. Провёл эксперимент,установил Git на другой машине. Выяснилось, что при разных условиях диалог установки Git на разных машинах может быть неодинаковым. Зависит от того, что у вас уже установлено в систему, касаемо SSH клиентов например (putty/plink...) и еще чего-то. На этой второй машине нет Putty, поэтому и диалога с выбором Putty или OpenSSH не было. Автоматом установился OpenSSH и всё работает. И на проблемной тачке переустановил Git, выбрав OpenSSH, где просили. Всё заработало. Буду пробовать выяснять, где проблема связки Git и Putty, или подскажите, кто знает.

Answer (score 1):

Может кому-то может помочь. Только что столкнулся с такой проблемой. На других машинах все работает. На моей так же все работало до сегодняшнего дня. Подключение через ssh. Windows 10 64bit. Не знаю, что к этому привело, но как оказалось слетел ключ, открыл pageant по пути `C:\Program Files (x86)\GitExtensions\PuTTY` добавил еще раз ключ и все заработало.